# Spring Social 1.0.3 Connect Interceptor Ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-social

I'm adding a Facebook connection interceptor and it is not being called.  I've upgraded from version 1.0.2 to 1.0.3 thinking it might be a bug but with no avail.  The config is being processed and addInterceptor method is being called (checked through debugging). Sign in works as expected. The interceptor type is Facebook. Can't figure out the problem.  Please help.

My Social Config:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionSignUp;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.SignInAdapter;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory;

import com.test.security.ConnectionSignUpImpl;
import com.test.security.SignInAdapterImpl;
import com.test.social.facebook.PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor;
import com.test.social.facebook.RedirectAfterConnectInterceptor;


@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {
      @Inject
        private Environment environment;
      @Inject
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Inject
        private TextEncryptor textEncryptor;
        @Value("${app.url}")
        private String applicationUrl;
        @Value("${facebook.clientId}")
        private String facebookClientId;
        @Value("${facebook.clientSecret}")
        private String facebookClientSecret;


    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            facebookClientId,
            facebookClientSecret));



        return registry;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
        }
        return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(authentication.getName());
    }

    @Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
                dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), textEncryptor);
        repository.setConnectionSignUp(connectionSignUp());
        return repository;
    }
     @Bean
     public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
         return Encryptors.noOpText();
     }

     @Bean
        public ConnectController connectController() {
         ConnectController controller = new ConnectController(
                    connectionFactoryLocator(), connectionRepository());
                controller.setApplicationUrl(applicationUrl);
                controller.addInterceptor(new RedirectAfterConnectInterceptor());

                return controller;
        }

     @Bean
     public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
         ProviderSignInController controller = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator(), 
                 usersConnectionRepository(), signInAdapter());

         controller.setSignUpUrl("/register");
         controller.setSignInUrl("/");


         return controller;
     }

     @Bean
     public SignInAdapter signInAdapter() {
         return new SignInAdapterImpl();
     }


     @Bean
     public ConnectionSignUp connectionSignUp() {
         return new ConnectionSignUpImpl();
     }

}
```

My Interceptor:

```
package com.test.social.facebook;

import org.springframework.social.connect.Connection;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectInterceptor;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

public class RedirectAfterConnectInterceptor implements ConnectInterceptor<Facebook> {

    public void preConnect(ConnectionFactory<Facebook> connectionFactory, MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters, WebRequest request) {
            System.out.println("PRE CONNECT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            request.setAttribute("redirectUrl", "test.com", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);

    }

    public void postConnect(Connection<Facebook> connection, WebRequest request) {

        System.out.println("POST CONNECT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        String redirectUrl = (String)request.getAttribute("redirectUrl", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
        if (redirectUrl != null) {
            System.out.println("REDIRECT URL: " + redirectUrl);
            request.removeAttribute("redirectUrl", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add `ProviderSignInInterceptor` instead of `ConnectInterceptor`? Because in the question you mentioned that you did test for sign in functionality, and not for connect functionality.

Comment: ProviderSignInInterceptor does not exist for the latest release version, only in the milestone release.  I'm following the showcase example

Comment: Does `ConnectInterceptor` get called when you test connect functionality? To make sure that you test it right you need to remove previous authorization on facebook side first.

Comment: If you do not remove facebook authentication before test then previously persisted connection will be reused and (I am pretty sure) `ConnectInterceptor` will not be called.

Comment: I've tried that already, removed the persistent connections, the connect interceptor does not get called.  I've just tried the M3 release with SignInInterceptor and it is also ignored

Comment: Have you removed existed authorization from your Facebook profile? I mean go to your facebook user options page and remove authorization for your app.

Comment: I'm using the ProviderSignInInterceptor now, shouldn't it intercept on every sign in?

Comment: Tried removing the app from facebook account also, no go

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake, I've added Spring Social controller package to the component-scan, I've had a mix up